# Performance of simple filesearch in Java

Tags: java, performance, file-io

We run a webserver that has to serve files from a rather large directory, so finding the file via a simple wildcard search like "abcd*jklp*" has serious performance issues.

Is there a way (a trick or a library) to speed up file search in Java? If not, is there a simple caching solution, such that each search is done only once unless the application explicitly empties the cache?

Comment: Is it possible to cache all the files in the tree or directory? Looking up matching filesnames from the tree will likely be much faster then going to the OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your web application starts (and every x minutes after that) cache every file you intend to serve in a static variable. When users search for a specific file search your static cache rather than running a search on the actual file server.

Caching everything works great if all you allow is searching on a file name. You could store every file path in a List/Array. If the list/array is already sorted you can use a binary search for user search queries. If there are wild card(s) generate the proper RegEx.

For full text searching of file contents, storing it all statically would not be feasible. Do something lazy like back your files with a database or buy a search appliance like GSA http://www.google.com/enterprise/search/gsa.html

Comment: Full text search of file contents is not necessary. Do you suggest to invalidate the cache on a fixed timout and rebuild it completely? This sounds costly...

Comment: @Tim van Beek - Costly compared to what? Searching through every file on the file server for every search request is costly. You could generate a new cache every X minutes or just add(new) / remove(deleted) files from the current static cache. But you will still have to re-iterate through all of the files on the file server once in a while.

Comment: The last sentence seems to answer my question, I was curious if there is a notify mechanism for changes on the file system that one could use instead of re-iterating once in a while.

Comment: @TimvanBeek you are right! There is a file change notification API in Java. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html It is in the NIO. It is the "Watch Service API" in Java.Nio.File package. However, it's implementation or performance/efficiency probably varies with underlying OS features.

Answer (score 0):

The "trick" in searching is to provide as much information as possible to the initial query.  If my desired file is called BobAndAlice and my input String is `B*` it will be theoretically slower than the search utilizing `Bo*` .  Caching works by building a lookup table in a fashion similar to a HashMap for the sake of this discussion.  In essence each search, upon submit, will be checked against your `Query Map` and if it has been run and the `Cache Emptied` flag is set to false you will then hit the `Lookup Table` which will be all of the pointers that came from the results of the executed query.  Thereby allowing for `fast` lookups of already retrieved data.  Where you can run into issue is if you store duplicate file copies instead of the pointer to the file.  The same process will be valid for actually serving the file to the user.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem like a Java problem. Its more like a algorithmic problem. What I understood from the problem is that you have large number of files in a given directory  and given a wild card pattern string you need to process the file matching that criteria. This essentially the problem of String matching where you have lot of strings and need to find only those which match particular criteria. There are lot of options through which you can do this however I will suggest approach of **Suffix tree** for this scenario as it will give almost o(n) performance in file search.